# Transform an XMLObject with XMLElements with empty attributes

Tags: xml

I would like to transform a an `XMLObject` so as to replace all the non empty attributes of the `XMLElements` by empty attributes.

The aim is to have a smaller structure that I could visualize with `ExpressionTreePlot`.

May you help me to define a appropriated code with this sample to start ?

```
xml = XMLObject[
  "Document"][{XMLObject["Doctype"]["DEXXMLDoc", 
   "System" -> "DEXXMLDoc.DTD"]}, 
 XMLElement[
  "DEXXMLDoc", {"name" -> "RSM-a.xml", "creator" -> "DX8", 
   "version" -> "8.0.6"}, {XMLElement[
    "designInfo", {"studyType" -> "ResponseSurface", 
     "designType" -> "CCD", "noOfRuns" -> "20", "noOfFactors" -> "3", 
     "noOfResponses" -> "2"}, {XMLElement[
      "designNotes", {}, {"This data file created by Design-Expert \
6"}]}], XMLElement[
    "blockInfo", {}, {XMLElement[
      "block", {"code" -> "0", "name" -> "Block 1"}, {}], 
     XMLElement["block", {"code" -> "1", "name" -> "Block 2"}, {}]}]
   }
  ]
 ]
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

```
Block[{XMLElement},
    XMLElement[x_, y : Except[{}], z_] := XMLElement[x, {}, z];
    xml
]
```

> ```
> XMLObject[
>   "Document"][{XMLObject["Doctype"]["DEXXMLDoc", 
>    "System" -> "DEXXMLDoc.DTD"]}, 
>  XMLElement[
>   "DEXXMLDoc", {}, {XMLElement[
>     "designInfo", {}, {XMLElement[
>       "designNotes", {}, {"This data file created by Design-Expert \
> 6"}]}], XMLElement[
>     "blockInfo", {}, {XMLElement["block", {}, {}], 
>      XMLElement["block", {}, {}]}]}]]
> ```